# No terminal output when running php command for a php file

Tags: php, shell

i have this file  :

**~/abd.php**

```
<?php
    echo 5+5;
?>
```

i run this command on terminal

```
php5 ~/abd.php
```

i expect to get 10 . However, No output found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it output before the prompt, e.g:

10user@server:~#

If so, try adding a newline.

Comment: where to add new line and how ?